# Is such graph possible to plot Using Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to re-implement an existing graph in Highchart. I would like to know if Highchart supports such graph. If yes, Please suggest me the API/Documents that would help me in this direction.
Below is the image of what graph would look like:
[How the graph should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KucqC.png)

About Chart:

- It looks as if multiple charts are combined into charts.
- x-axis for all the 'Events' is time(2- years default).
- Each 'Event' graph can be of different type (point, spline, continuous etc.)
- Can I customize the representation of data-point in each 'Event chart' differently. i.e.(triangle,square etc).

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You can create 4 separate y axes, each with a *top* and *height* setting, so that you can plot your separate series on the same x axis, as you have illustrated. Each data series, and even each data point, can have separate point marker properties (like triangle, square, etc)

Answer (score 2):

An example of some of the features you've asked about:

1) using multiple y axes, stacked vertically, you can achieve the layout that you want:

```
yAxis: [{  
    top: 10,
  height: 60,
  offset: 0,
  title: { text: 'Plot 1'}
},{
    top: 80,
  height: 60,
  offset: 0,
  title: { text: 'Plot 2'}
},{
    top: 140,
  height: 120,
  offset: 0,
  title: { text: 'Plot 3'}
},{
    top: 270,
  height: 60,
  offset: 0,
  title: { text: 'Plot 4'}
}]
```

On each series, you can specify individual marker settings:

```
marker: {
  enabled: true,
  symbol: 'triangle',
  radius: 6,
  ...etc...
},
```

You can set a date-time x axis type:

```
xAxis: { 
  type: 'datetime'
}
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/py5cznd7/

Comment: Thank you, This will help me get started!!

Comment: I am having one more challenge. Could you help me out with [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425036/is-expanding-a-graph-to-show-further-details-possible-in-highchart-highstock)